# Satmarer minhogim

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, mesorah-tradition, nuschaot, satmar, minhagim

I'm looking for a source to learn the minhogim of Satmar chassidus. I wonder how different or similar it is from a galitzianer chassidus for example, maybe it has non-chassidic hungarian influences, etc. I'm specifically interested in english or yiddish sources available online, but hebrew and physical ones are alright too.

Comment: I do not know if you are looking for a physical source, if yes, you should check out: https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/mhr-i-br-h-i-hlq-a-mnhgi-qvdw-satmar.html#tab-label-description-title

Comment: @Shmuel I appreciate the information, it's just a problem for me right now to get books like that one because of the exchange rate.

Comment: You can access the product @Shmuel found here - https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A7-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%90%D7%98%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A8-%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A2-%D7%97%D7%90